# In this drawing of the Avengers, who's the guy on the right?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, the very first scene shows a kid's drawing of the Avengers' battle with aliens in New York City:

[image]

Who's the guy on the right hand side with the sword?

[image]

At first I thought it was Clint Barton/Hawkeye, but after a closer look the important details don't match. Here's a photo of Clint from that battle:

[image]

([source](http://savagemcu.blogspot.com/2016/03/clint-bartonhawkeye.html))

There is a superficial resemblance, but in the drawing:

- No bow or arrows or visible quiver / sword or scimitar instead
- Light gray outfit instead of dark / black
- Wearing what looks like ammo belts or bandolier

The "scimitar" does have a bow-like shape, but why would you hold a bow at the end instead of by the central grip?

Now granted, this is supposed to be a kid's drawing and you wouldn't expect perfect accuracy. But all the other Avengers are correct in their main elements and the artist (in-universe) clearly took their time to put in a lot of details. So while it could be Clint just depicted incorrectly, I'm more likely to think it's someone else.

But who is it?

Comment: He also seems to be wearing bandoliers, which doesn't make sense for someone wielding a sword.

Comment: Isn't that that "sword" just a poorly drawn bow?

Comment: @Acccumulation Early art designs show Ronin with a chest strap.

Comment: @Acccumulation Bandoliers don't make sense for a bow either.  It would only really make sense if he carried a shotgun, or possibly some kind of machine gun, depending on the type.

Comment: He could hold his special arrow tips in the bandoliers.

Comment: If we're going with theories, I think this is more likely to be another instance of the running joke that Hawkeye doesn't seem like he's in the same league as the other Avengers. This kid loves the team, but doesn't pay enough attention to Hawkeye to even realise he carries a bow and arrow.

Answer (score 39):

### It IS Hawkeye, depicting his Ronin character from *Avengers: Endgame*.

[image]

According to [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/hawkeye-ronin-mcu-identity-spiderman-homecoming-drawing/), it is an *Easter Egg* revealing Hawkeye’s future transformation into Ronin:

> Clint Barton skipped *Avengers: Infinity War* only to return as Ronin in *Endgame*, but **his transformation was teased as early as *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.**
>
> The transformation of Hawkeye into Ronin was seen in *Avengers: Endgame*, but **it was actually first teased during *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.** The Avengers' resident marksman skipped the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* altogether as he served home detention following his actions in *Captain America: Civil War*. By the time he came back to the MCU forefront, he had already ditched his old persona as Hawkeye and assumed a new one as the masterless samurai.
>
> In the months leading up to *Avengers: Endgame*, there were persistent rumors about this dark turn for Clint Barton even prior to the release of any footage for the film, thanks to the arrival of tie-in merchandise depicting him as such. The trailers for *Endgame* further teased his turn into Ronin, but it turns out that **fans were already tipped off to his imminent introduction as early as 2017 in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.**
>
> During the prologue scene of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, we see Adrian Toomes (Michael Keaton) look at a drawing of the Avengers during the battle of New York made by his daughter, Liz. He and his people were gearing up to take care of the rubble left by Earth's Mightiest Heroes' fight against Loki (Tom Hiddleston) and his Chitauri army in New York when he held up the illustration recounting the six original Avengers in the middle of the battle. However, while every single hero looked pretty much like themselves, **Barton's Hawkeye is interestingly carrying a different weapon than his signature bow and arrow. Instead, he's carrying a sword - something he wouldn't do until *Avengers: Endgame*, effectively spoiling what would be his character's future trajectory as Ronin.**
>
> During the production of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Marvel Studios creatives were deep into mapping out how *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Endgame* would pan out. And it's safe to assume that it included the decision to have Barton sit out the initial fight against Thanos, before his family is then killed by the Snap, which was what justified his dark turn as Ronin in *Avengers: Endgame*. It's entirely possible, then, that **this was a knowing Easter egg for the film**, especially since the MCU loves its moments of foreshadowing.
>
> Of course, the proper Hawkeye did return in *Avengers: Endgame* as well, but his transformation into Ronin was one of the most discussed parts of the movie prior to its release. ***Spider-Man: Homecoming* might've just intended it as a fun Easter egg and a nod towards something that might happen** - although its opening scene already has one major mistake - but looking back **we can see it as a fun tease of what Hawkeye would become**.

Comment: I don’t doubt that this is right but this is just ScreenRant’s theory on the matter? Is there anything more official?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot not that I've been able to find so far.

Comment: The drawing looks further off Ronin costume than it does the Hawkeye costume, although it could just have been an early design. If I had to guess without context, which Marvel character was in that picture, I'd say Swordsman (without mask) because of the chest design, but he has close ties to Hawkeye as well.

Comment: @KMo Early art designs show Ronin with a chest strap. Plus as an Easter Egg and a child's drawing I wouldn't look too much into it. It would be very strange for it _not_ to be Clint.

Comment: FWIW I've since checked the usual places (art of books and searched for interviews) and have turned up nothing. It can't really be anyone else so this has to be correct but there doesn't seem to be anything explicit to back it up.

Comment: The fact that both the drawing and Hawkeye outfit are sleeveless kind of supports that version - as Ronin he wears full arm-covering armor.  The bandoliers can be forgiven, that's just the kind of detail a kid would make up.  But it is definitely weird to see him in the Hawkeye outfit with the wrong weapon.  (It's not even the right kind of sword for Ronin, more of a scimitar than a katana.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Most children's drawings of swords look like either bananas or triangles. I'm not sure the distinction between scimitar and katana exists outside of the artist's imagination.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yes, my mind was going that this could have been based on an earlier Swordsman inspired design for Ronin, which would have been a nod to the guy who taught Clint swordsmanship in the comics. Do you have a link to the earlier designs for Ronin? It would add some credence to this answer if there are closer similarities to the drawing.

Comment: @KMo no link, I was flipping through the “Art of” book for Endgame. There’s a few in there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate take, alluded to in the comments:

That *is* Hawkeye, because it *is* a bow.

He's holding it in the middle. We see the top half, curving around his front, and don't see the bottom half because it curves around behind him.

Yes, he seems to have bandoliers on, but those don't make any more sense for Ronin than they do for Hawkeye. It's a kid's drawing. I used to put bandoliers on people all the time for no reason, too. Blame G.I. Joes.